# RESTful API for related objects

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, rest, database-design, architecture

I am fairly new to REST and I have been struggling to map out RESTful requests for objects that are related by foreign keys in a mySQL database.

I have following objects and their relationships are in linear order:

```
Quiz_course [1]
Quiz_meta_block [2]
Quiz_block [3]
Quiz_question [4]
```

So far I have come up with the following `GET` requests:

```
// Retrieve all quiz_course(s)
api/quiz_course/

// Retrieve quiz_course by id
api/quiz_course/{id}

// Retrieve all quiz_meta_blocks related to a quiz_course id
api/quiz_course/{id}/quiz_meta_block

// Retrieve a quiz_meta_block that is related to a quiz_course_id
api/quiz_course/{id}/quiz_meta_block/{id}
```

But then I hit a wall when trying to get quiz_questions :

```
// Retrieve all quiz_questions that is related to a quiz_course_id
api/quiz_course/{id}/quiz_meta_block/quiz_block/quiz_question/
```

Is my representation accurate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what a block or meta block is in the context of a course, but I would go with something like the below. No need to prefix everything with quiz_*

```
../courses
../courses/n
../courses/n/meta-blocks
../courses/n/meta-blocks/n
../courses/n/meta-blocks/n/blocks
../courses/n/meta-blocks/n/blocks/n
../courses/n/meta-blocks/n/blocks/n/questions
../courses/n/meta-blocks/n/blocks/n/questions/n
```

You could also give direct access to, say, all questions in a course like this:

```
../courses/n/questions
```